# Brightening Button Color

Tags: android, android-layout, app-inventor, android-ide

I am trying to make the button color bright when holding it and when released it turns into another bright color, using the `MIT APP INVENTOR`.

I tried doing it, but every time the color looks faded when clicking it. The code I put together is in the image.

[image: Code]

The result when holding the "YES" button is the image down below, the green is faded. After releasing the button the color should give a bright grey color, but that too is faded.

[image]

How can I make them look bright?

Comment: you are using an emulator... what happens, if you try a real device?

Comment: For my first click, it shows Bright green and bright grey, but after my first click every click shows faded green and faded grey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the button properties in the Designer and untick Show Feedback. This should make your button `bright`. You only need to do this with the Classic theme. Other themes should give you your bright colour without this change.

Comment: Oh ok, I see it. Thank you. It works well.